How can I generate an Azure artifact file after a SonarQube pipeline scan?
I have a NodeJs app and a pipeline that runs for my Azure repository:
jobs-sonar-scan.yaml - pipeline
jobs:
  - job: SonarAnalysis
    displayName: 'Sonar Analysis'
    steps:
      # Prepare Analysis Configuration task
      - task: SonarQubePrepare@6
        inputs:
          SonarQube: 'my-azure-sonar-connection'
          scannerMode: 'my-name'
          configMode: 'manual'
          cliProjectKey: 'my-cli'
          extraProperties: |
            sonar.tests.inclusions=**/*.test.ts
            sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/*
      
      # Run Code Analysis task
      - task: SonarQubeAnalyze@6
        inputs:
          jdkVersion: 'JAVA_HOME_17_X64'  # Fixed typo here
      
      # Publish Quality Gate Result task
      - task: SonarQubePublish@6
        inputs:
          pollingTimeoutSec: '300'

The pipeline runs well and sends the report back to the Sonar dashboard. However, at the end of the pipeline, I want to generate and publish an artifact file with the destination report/sonar-report.json. I have tried something like this:
 - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
               New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path "$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/report/sonar" -Force
               
      - task: CopyFiles@2
        inputs:
          sourceFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
          contents: '**/$(BuildConfiguration)/**/?(*.exe|*.dll|*.pdb)'
          targetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/report/sonar'
          cleanTargetFolder: true  # Optionally clean the target folder before copying

      - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
        inputs:
          pathToPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/report/sonar'
          artifactName: drop```

But it doesn't work. I am fairly new to this kind of stuff. Thank you!

I want to generate an artifact report from my SonarQube scan in the pipeline summary.

Can you find the sonar-report.json on your pipeline workspace? As far as I know, the sonar-report.json file can be found in SonarQube UI. And it will not be generated during the Pipeline task execution.
